# What simple text editors exist that do not convert files as TextEdit does?

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor

Is there a simple text editor like Notepad (or Notepad++) on Windows for OS X? TextEdit cannot open all types of files and TextWrangler is not "simple", for my opinion TextWrangler is meant to work with projects not simply single files.

I want to open *any* types of files and see their source/binary code. Then I want to be able to save the file without any auto converting (as TextEdit does).

Comment: TextWrangler's no more complicated than Notepad++, and I'd say a good sight less complicated - it has neither the plugin system nor the custom syntax coloring that Notepad++ has.

Comment: Also, TextEdit will open any type of file you want - you just need to force it to (just like you would Notepad on Windows).

Comment: Further, I'm voting to close this as Not A Real Question because you don't mention what features in TextWrangler you find complicated or what sorts of files you work with. (Basically: give more detail.)

Comment: It's hard to answer this without explaining what "simple" means – I see you don't want TextWrangler to be the answer, but I can't figure out by what criteria you rule it out. Perhaps you can clarify and we can reopen the question.

Answer (score 4):

[Textmate 2](https://github.com/textmate/textmate)
[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com)
[Subethaedit](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/)
[smultron](http://www.peterborgapps.com/smultron/)

Comment: Good choices, but not less "complicated" than TextWrangler, whatever that means.

Comment: I agree, and since I was unable to understand how he found Text Wrangler "complicated", I threw out some other easy-to-use GUI based editors /shrug

Comment: You forgot [MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases).  Obviously that's much less complicated than TextWrangler.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest equivalent would be [NovoEdit](http://software.terenovo.com/novoedit/).  I find NovoEdit to be an extremely simple, yet helpful text editor when it comes to handling any kind of file.  This reminds me of Windows' Notepad.  And although I agree with @CajunLuke on the fact that TextEdit *is* able to open anything by forcing it to, I see myself using NovoEdit far more often than TextEdit simply because of its speed and ease-of-use.